# Getting symbolicated stack traces from backtrace_symbols() in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, symbols, crash-reports, backtrace, human-readable

Prior to iOS 6, calling callStackSymbols() (also what -[NSException callStackSymbols] uses) would provide human readable stack frames. However, with iOS 6, this no longer the case and only addresses are provided (eg 57  CoreFoundation                      0x367ba5db  + 118) for Apple libraries.

How may a fully-symbolicated backtrace be programmatically obtained in iOS 6?